# Run the athena query on specific s3 file

Tags: amazon-s3

I have created lambda funtion which fetch the s3 bucket name and file name on every s3 put event .

I want run the athena query on the file name which is fetch in above lambda event.

Answer (score 0):

Athena can only query data that is in S3, and it needs a table definition pointing to S3

if that's the case, and you want to query a particular file in S3, then you can use the `$path` pseudovariable to filter by path name

`select * from mytable where "$path" = 's3://bucket/path/to/file.json'`